# Class loading take long time to load a class with a big switch-case block

Tags: java

I did a quick benchmarking test of Java class loading for classes with a big switch block. I have 10 classes with some 30-40 switch blocks. It took on my box ~3 secs with Java8 (Java7 took only about 1.9 secs).

Could anyone please explain what happens behind the scenes while loading the classes with big switch blocks, and why is it so slow?

EDIT:

The problem seems with enums. It the enum size is big, the class loading takes time. Below is an example.

```
public abstract class A {
    public static enum ENUM {
        A100, A113, A126, A139, A152, A165, A178, A191, A204, A217, A230, A243, A256, A269, A282, A295,
        A308, A321, A334, A347, A360, A373, A386, A399, A412, A425, A438, A451, A464, A477, A490, A503,
        A516, A529, A542, A555, A568, A581, A594, A607, A620, A633, A646, A659, A672, A685, A698, A711,
        A724, A737, A750, A763, A776, A789, A802, A815, A828, A841, A854, A867, A880, A893, A906, A919,
        A932, A945, A958, A971, A984, A997, A1010, A1023, A1036, A1049, A1062, A1075, A1088, A1101, A1114,
        A1127, A1140, A1153, A1166, A1179, A1192, A1205, A1218, A1231, A1244, A1257, A1270, A1283, A1296,
        A1309, A1322, A1335, A1348, A1361, A1374, A1387, A1400, A1413, A1426, A1439, A1452, A1465, A1478,
        A1491, A1504, A1517, A1530, A1543, A1556, A1569, A1582, A1595, A1608, A1621, A1634, A1647, A1660,
        A1673, A1686, A1699, A1712, A1725, A1738, A1751, A1764, A1777, A1790, A1803, A1816, A1829, A1842,
        A1855, A1868, A1881, A1894, A1907, A1920, A1933, A1946, A1959, A1972, A1985, A1998, A2011, A2024,
        A2037, A2050, A2063, A2076, A2089, A2102, A2115, A2128, A2141, A2154, A2167, A2180, A2193, A2206,
        A2219, A2232, A2245, A2258, A2271, A2284, A2297, A2310, A2323, A2336, A2349, A2362, A2375, A2388, 
        A2401, A2414, A2427, A2440, A2453, A2466, A2479, A2492, A2505, A2518, A2531, A2544, A2557, A2570,
        A2583, A2596, A2609, A2622, A2635, A2648, A2661, A2674, A2687, A2700, A2713, A2726, A2739, A2752,
        A2765, A2778, A2791, A2804, A2817, A2830, A2843, A2856, A2869, A2882, A2895, A2908, A2921, A2934,
        A2947, A2960, A2973, A2986, A2999, A3012, A3025, A3038, A3051, A3064, A3077, A3090, A3103, A3116, 
        A3129, A3142, A3155, A3168, A3181, A3194, A3207, A3220, A3233, A3246, A3259, A3272, A3285, A3298, 
        A3311, A3324, A3337, A3350, A3363, A3376, A3389, A3402, A3415, A3428, A3441, A3454, A3467, A3480,
        A3493, A3506, A3519, A3532, A3545, A3558, A3571, A3584, A3597, A3610, A3623, A3636, A3649, A3662, 
        A3675, A3688, A3701, A3714, A3727, A3740, A3753, A3766, A3779, A3792, A3805, A3818, A3831, A3844, 
        A3857, A3870, A3883, A3896, A3909, A3922, A3935, A3948, A3961, A3974, A3987, A4000, A4013, A4026,
        A4039, A4052, A4065, A4078, A4091, A4104, A4117, A4130, A4143, A4156, A4169, A4182, A4195, A4208, 
        A4221, A4234, A4247, A4260, A4273, A4286, A4299, A4312, A4325, A4338, A4351, A4364, A4377, A4390, 
        A4403, A4416, A4429, A4442, A4455, A4468, A4481, A4494, A4507, A4520, A4533, A4546, A4559, A4572, 
        A4585, A4598, A4611, A4624, A4637, A4650, A4663, A4676, A4689, A4702, A4715, A4728, A4741, A4754, 
        A4767, A4780, A4793, A4806, A4819, A4832, A4845, A4858, A4871, A4884, A4897, A4910, A4923, A4936, 
        A4949, A4962, A4975, A4988, A5001, A5014, A5027, A5040, A5053, A5066, A5079, A5092, A5105, A5118, 
        A5131, A5144, A5157, A5170, A5183, A5196, A5209, A5222, A5235, A5248, A5261, A5274, A5287, A5300, 
        A5313, A5326, A5339, A5352, A5365, A5378, A5391, A5404, A5417, A5430, A5443, A5456, A5469, A5482, 
        A5495, A5508, A5521, A5534, A5547, A5560, A5573, A5586, A5599, A5612, A5625, A5638, A5651, A5664, 
        A5677, A5690, A5703, A5716, A5729, A5742, A5755, A5768, A5781, A5794, A5807, A5820, A5833, A5846, 
        A5859, A5872, A5885, A5898, A5911, A5924, A5937, A5950, A5963, A5976, A5989, A6002, A6015, A6028, 
        A6041, A6054, A6067, A6080, A6093, A6106, A6119, A6132, A6145, A6158, A6171, A6184, A6197, A6210,
        A6223, A6236, A6249, A6262, A6275, A6288, A6301, A6314, A6327, A6340, A6353, A6366, A6379, A6392, 
        A6405, A6418, A6431, A6444, A6457, A6470, A6483, A6496, A6509, A6522, A6535, A6548, A6561, A6574,
        A6587, A6600, A6613, A6626, A6639, A6652, A6665, A6678, A6691, A6704, A6717, A6730, A6743, A6756, 
        A6769, A6782, A6795, A6808, A6821, A6834, A6847, A6860, A6873, A6886, A6899, A6912, A6925, A6938,
        A6951, A6964, A6977, A6990, A7003, A7016, A7029, A7042, A7055, A7068, A7081, A7094, A7107, A7120, 
        A7133, A7146, A7159, A7172, A7185, A7198, A7211, A7224, A7237, A7250, A7263, A7276, A7289, A7302, 
        A7315, A7328, A7341, A7354, A7367, A7380, A7393, A7406, A7419, A7432, A7445, A7458, A7471, A7484,
        A7497, A7510, A7523, A7536, A7549, A7562, A7575, A7588, A7601, A7614, A7627, A7640, A7653, A7666,
        A7679, A7692, A7705, A7718, A7731, A7744, A7757, A7770, A7783, A7796, A7809, A7822, A7835, A7848, 
        A7861, A7874, A7887, A7900, A7913, A7926, A7939, A7952, A7965, A7978, A7991, A8004, A8017, A8030,
        A8043, A8056, A8069, A8082, A8095, A8108, A8121, A8134, A8147, A8160, A8173, A8186, A8199, A8212, A8225,
        A8238, A8251, A8264, A8277, A8290, A8303, A8316, A8329, A8342, A8355, A8368, A8381, A8394, A8407,
        A8420, A8433, A8446, A8459, A8472, A8485, A8498, A8511, A8524, A8537, A8550, A8563, A8576, A8589, 
        A8602, A8615, A8628, A8641, A8654, A8667, A8680, A8693, A8706, A8719, A8732, A8745, A8758, A8771, 
        A8784, A8797, A8810, A8823, A8836, A8849, A8862, A8875, A8888, A8901, A8914, A8927, A8940, A8953, 
        A8966, A8979, A8992, A9005, A9018, A9031, A9044, A9057, A9070, A9083, A9096, A9109, A9122, A9135, 
        A9148, A9161, A9174, A9187, A9200, A9213, A9226, A9239, A9252, A9265, A9278, A9291, A9304, A9317,
        A9330, A9343, A9356, A9369, A9382, A9395, A9408, A9421, A9434, A9447, A9460, A9473, A9486, A9499, 
        A9512, A9525, A9538, A9551, A9564, A9577, A9590, A9603, A9616, A9629, A9642, A9655, A9668, A9681, 
        A9694, A9707, A9720, A9733, A9746, A9759, A9772, A9785, A9798, A9811, A9824, A9837, A9850, A9863,
        A9876, A9889, A9902, A9915, A9928, A9941, A9954, A9967, A9980, A9993, A10006, A10019, A10032, A10045,
        A10058, A10071, A10084, A10097, A10110, A10123, A10136, A10149, A10162, A10175, A10188, A10201, A10214,
        A10227, A10240, A10253, A10266, A10279, A10292, A10305, A10318, A10331, A10344, A10357, A10370, A10383,
        A10396, A10409, A10422, A10435, A10448, A10461, A10474, A10487, A10500, A10513, A10526, A10539, A10552,
        A10565, A10578, A10591, A10604, A10617, A10630, A10643, A10656, A10669, A10682, A10695, A10708, A10721,
        A10734, A10747, A10760, A10773, A10786, A10799, A10812, A10825, A10838, A10851, A10864, A10877, A10890,
        A10903, A10916, A10929, A10942, A10955, A10968, A10981, A10994, A11007, A11020, A11033, A11046, A11059, 
        A11072, A11085, A11098, A11111, A11124, A11137, A11150, A11163, A11176, A11189, A11202, A11215, A11228, 
        A11241, A11254, A11267, A11280, A11293, A11306, A11319, A11332, A11345, A11358, A11371, A11384, A11397, 
        A11410, A11423, A11436, A11449, A11462, A11475, A11488, A11501, A11514, A11527, A11540, A11553, A11566, 
        A11579, A11592, A11605, A11618, A11631, A11644, A11657, A11670, A11683, A11696, A11709, A11722, A11735, 
        A11748, A11761, A11774, A11787, A11800, A11813, A11826, A11839, A11852, A11865, A11878, A11891, A11904, 
        A11917, A11930, A11943, A11956, A11969, A11982, A11995, A12008, A12021, A12034, A12047, A12060, A12073, 
        A12086, A12099, A12112, A12125, A12138, A12151, A12164, A12177, A12190, A12203, A12216, A12229, A12242, 
        A12255, A12268, A12281, A12294, A12307, A12320, A12333, A12346, A12359, A12372, A12385, A12398, A12411, 
        A12424, A12437, A12450, A12463, A12476, A12489, A12502, A12515, A12528, A12541, A12554, A12567, A12580, 
        A12593, A12606, A12619, A12632, A12645, A12658, A12671, A12684, A12697, A12710, A12723, A12736, A12749, 
        A12762, A12775, A12788, A12801, A12814, A12827, A12840, A12853, A12866, A12879, A12892, A12905, A12918, 
        A12931, A12944, A12957, A12970, A12983, A12996, A13009, A13022, A13035, A13048, A13061, A13074, A13087, 
        A13100, A13113, A13126, A13139, A13152, A13165, A13178, A13191, A13204, A13217, A13230, A13243, A13256, 
        A13269, A13282, A13295, A13308, A13321, A13334, A13347, A13360, A13373, A13386, A13399, A13412, A13425, 
        A13438, A13451, A13464, A13477, A13490, A13503, A13516, A13529, A13542, A13555, A13568, A13581, A13594, 
        A13607, A13620, A13633, A13646, A13659, A13672, A13685, A13698, A13711, A13724, A13737, A13750, A13763, 
        A13776, A13789, A13802, A13815, A13828, A13841, A13854, A13867, A13880, A13893, A13906, A13919, A13932, 
        A13945, A13958, A13971, A13984, A13997, A14010, A14023, A14036, A14049, A14062, A14075, A14088, A14101, 
        A14114, A14127, A14140, A14153, A14166, A14179, A14192, A14205, A14218, A14231, A14244, A14257, A14270, 
        A14283, A14296, A14309, A14322, A14335, A14348, A14361, A14374, A14387, A14400, A14413, A14426, A14439, 
        A14452, A14465, A14478, A14491, A14504, A14517, A14530, A14543, A14556, A14569, A14582, A14595, A14608, 
        A14621, A14634, A14647, A14660, A14673, A14686, A14699, A14712, A14725, A14738, A14751, A14764, A14777, 
        A14790, A14803, A14816, A14829, A14842, A14855, A14868, A14881, A14894, A14907, A14920, A14933, A14946, 
        A14959, A14972, A14985, A14998, A15011, A15024, A15037, A15050, A15063, A15076, A15089, A15102, A15115, 
        A15128, A15141, A15154, A15167, A15180, A15193, A15206, A15219, A15232, A15245, A15258, A15271, A15284, 
        A15297, A15310, A15323, A15336, A15349, A15362, A15375, A15388, A15401, A15414, A15427, A15440, A15453, 
        A15466, A15479, A15492, A15505, A15518, A15531, A15544, A15557, A15570, A15583, A15596, A15609, A15622, 
        A15635, A15648, A15661, A15674, A15687, A15700, A15713, A15726, A15739, A15752, A15765, A15778, A15791, 
        A15804, A15817, A15830, A15843, A15856, A15869, A15882, A15895, A15908, A15921, A15934, A15947, A15960, 
        A15973, A15986, A15999, A16012, A16025, A16038, A16051, A16064, A16077, A16090, A16103, A16116, A16129, 
        A16142, A16155, A16168, A16181, A16194, A16207, A16220, A16233, A16246, A16259, A16272, A16285, A16298, 
        A16311, A16324, A16337, A16350, A16363, A16376, A16389, A16402, A16415, A16428, A16441, A16454, A16467, 
        A16480, A16493, A16506, A16519, A16532, A16545, A16558, A16571, A16584, A16597, A16610, A16623, A16636, 
        A16649, A16662, A16675, A16688, A16701, A16714, A16727, A16740, A16753, A16766, A16779, A16792, A16805, 
        A16818, A16831, A16844, A16857, A16870, A16883, A16896, A16909, A16922, A16935, A16948, A16961, A16974, 
        A16987, A17000, A17013, A17026, A17039, A17052, A17065, A17078, A17091, A17104, A17117, A17130, A17143, 
        A17156, A17169, A17182, A17195, A17208, A17221, A17234, A17247, A17260, A17273, A17286, A17299, A17312, 
        A17325, A17338, A17351, A17364, A17377, A17390, A17403, A17416, A17429, A17442, A17455, A17468, A17481, 
        A17494, A17507, A17520, A17533, A17546, A17559, A17572, A17585, A17598, A17611, A17624, A17637, A17650, 
        A17663, A17676, A17689, A17702, A17715, A17728, A17741, A17754, A17767, A17780, A17793, A17806, A17819, 
        A17832, A17845, A17858, A17871, A17884, A17897, A17910, A17923, A17936, A17949, A17962, A17975, A17988, 
        A18001, A18014, A18027, A18040, A18053, A18066, A18079, A18092, A18105, A18118, A18131, A18144, A18157, 
        A18170, A18183, A18196, A18209, A18222, A18235, A18248, A18261, A18274, A18287, A18300, A18313, A18326, 
        A18339, A18352, A18365, A18378, A18391, A18404, A18417, A18430, A18443, A18456, A18469, A18482, A18495, 
        A18508, A18521, A18534, A18547, A18560, A18573, A18586, A18599, A18612, A18625, A18638, A18651, A18664, 
        A18677, A18690, A18703, A18716, A18729, A18742, A18755, A18768, A18781, A18794, A18807, A18820, A18833, 
        A18846, A18859, A18872, A18885, A18898, A18911, A18924, A18937, A18950, A18963, A18976, A18989, A19002, 
        A19015, A19028, A19041, A19054, A19067, A19080, A19093, A19106, A19119, A19132, A19145, A19158, A19171, 
        A19184, A19197, A19210, A19223, A19236, A19249, A19262, A19275, A19288, A19301, A19314, A19327, A19340, 
        A19353, A19366, A19379, A19392, A19405, A19418, A19431, A19444, A19457, A19470, A19483, A19496, A19509, 
        A19522, A19535, A19548, A19561, A19574, A19587,
    }

    public abstract float getValue(int a, ENUM input);
}

public class A1 extends A {
    @Override
    public float getValue(int a, ENUM input) {
        float ret = input.ordinal();

        switch (input) {
        case A100:
            ret = a / 100;
            break;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}

public class A2 extends A {
    @Override
    public float getValue(int a, ENUM input) {
        float ret = input.ordinal();

        switch (input) {
        case A100:
            ret = a / 100;
            break;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}

public class Load {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new A1().getValue(10, ENUM.A10032);
        System.out.println("Time taken - A1:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));

        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new A2().getValue(10, ENUM.A10032);
        System.out.println("Time taken - A2:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Time taken - A1:242
Time taken - A2:209
```

Comment: The further interesting numbers would be how large the .class files actually are and how many case statements there is on average in each switch.

Comment: Have you measured load times of similar sized classes? Otherwise you'd measure loading times between Java 7 and 8.

Comment: Disassemble with `javap -c`. There is a known compiler optimization strategy that converts the switch in a tree of if-then-else and jump-tables, to prevent having holes in the jump table. Maybe some such (costly) evaluation occurs.

Comment: Blimey, that's one massive enum. Why?

Comment: And how can you write a switch/case statement so big without any mistakes?

Comment: @pavan.mankala Of course it isn't, you have to read a 80k class file, process it, then create 1500 instances.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77526/discussion-between-pavan-mankala-and-biziclop).

Comment: The class files of A1 and A2 are really large ~70KB. If I decompile A1 and A2 class a large SwitchTable is initialized statically, with all the enums in this. It looks like most of the time is spent in preparing this SwithTable, during class loading of A1 and A2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I worked out the problem myself with hints from above Comments by @Joop Eggen & @SpaceTrucker.

The generated class files from A1 and A1 are ~70KB. In these generated class files, the switch statement is optimized using **static** [TableSwitch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10), as enums are contiguous integers.

This table switch has **all** the enums, without any regards to the number used enums in switch-case block. ***Most of the time spent during class loading is in creating and populating this big TableSwitch.***

It is interesting why Oracles's Java 8 takes twice the time as Java 7 to load such a class with tableswitch.

It would also be useful if there is an option to choose between TableSwitch and LookupSwitch.